# How to set Eclipse CDT configuration build directory programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

[image: Cpp Project Properties]I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in to help my colleagues create C++ projects build configurations from a simple user interface. The only build configuration parameter I can't set programmatically is the project build location, surrounded with a red box in the above image.

I was looking for a function of `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.IConfiguration` to do that, but I didn't find any. Can you help me please on this? I'm using Eclipse 4.6.3 and CDT 9.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [CDT source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/ui/properties/BuilderSettingsTab.java?h=CDT_9_8_1#n451), that dialog's code sets the build path using `IConfiguration.getEditableBuilder().setBuildPath()`.